# An optimized way of summing every 3 elements in a matrix without using a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

An example of an array

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  6,  8,  3,  5,  6,  8,  9,  1,  2]])
```

I want an efficient way of getting this result without using a loop:

```
result = array([[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [16, 17, 16, 14, 19, 23, 18, 12]])
```

where the first 3 elements are summed (1+2+3) and then (2+3+4) and so on.

Comment: There *will* be a loop, whether you explicitely write it with `for` or a list comprehension, or use any function that runs the loop inside.

Comment: Yeah I had those two scenarios, I wanted something optimized in a way. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 4):

Numpy has [sliding window view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) included:

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 6, 8, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2]])

out = sliding_window_view(x, 3, axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)
print(out)
```

Print:

```
[[ 6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27]
 [16 17 16 14 19 23 18 12]]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Never knew numpy had a sliding window. @Andrej

Comment: The OP needs an efficient method. However, sliding_window_view() documentation says "For many applications using a sliding window view can be convenient, but potentially very slow. [...] Nevertheless, for small window sizes, when no custom algorithm exists, or as a prototyping and developing tool, this function can be a good solution."

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of every 3 elements, the following 1-liner will suffice

```py
result = arr[:, :-2] + arr[:, 1:-1] + arr[:, 2:]
```

---

However, for the more general case of every `n` elements, consider the following

```py
n = 3
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                [2, 6, 8, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2]])
```

we can first get the cumulative sum across the rows

```py
row_cumsum = np.cumsum(arr, axis=1)
# [[ 1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55]
#  [ 2  8 16 19 24 30 38 47 48 50]]
```

Create an array that has a column of 0 to the start of this cumulative array but without the last `n` columns

```py
trimmed = np.hstack((np.zeros((row_cumsum.shape[0], 1), dtype=int), row_cumsum[:,:-n]))
# [[ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28]
#  [ 0  2  8 16 19 24 30 38]]
```

Then simply subtract from the `n`-th column of our cumulative array with this trimmed array

```py
results =  row_cumsum[:, n-1:] - trimmed
# [[ 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55]      [[ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28]
#  [16 19 24 30 38 47 48 50]]  -   [ 0  2  8 16 19 24 30 38]]
#
# = [[ 6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27]
#    [16 17 16 14 19 23 18 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  6,  8,  3,  5,  6,  8,  9,  1,  2]])
```

You can get your elements by:

```
first_value = tuple(zip(a[0],a[0][1:],a[0][2:]))

((1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (3, 4, 5),
 (4, 5, 6),
 (5, 6, 7),
 (6, 7, 8),
 (7, 8, 9),
 (8, 9, 10))

list(map(sum, first_value))
#[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
```

---

```
second_value = tuple(zip(a[1],a[1][1:],a[1][2:]))

((2, 6, 8),
 (6, 8, 3),
 (8, 3, 5),
 (3, 5, 6),
 (5, 6, 8),
 (6, 8, 9),
 (8, 9, 1),
 (9, 1, 2))


list(map(sum, second_value))
#[16, 17, 16, 14, 19, 23, 18, 12]
```

---

```
np.array([list(map(sum, first_value)),list(map(sum, second_value))])
#array([[ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [16, 17, 16, 14, 19, 23, 18, 12]])
```

---

---

Method 2:

Simply by using numpy slicing:

First element

```
a[0][:-2] + a[0][1:][:-1] + a[0][2:]

#output
array([ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27])
```

Second element

```
a[1][:-2] + a[1][1:][:-1] + a[1][2:]

#output
array([16, 17, 16, 14, 19, 23, 18, 12])
```

Or As suggested by @Ignatius

```
a[:,:-2] + a[:,1:-1] + a[:,2:]

#output
array([[ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [16, 17, 16, 14, 19, 23, 18, 12]])
```

Comment: yeah, but I am looking for an efficient way to do that. I am trying so hard not to use a loop for that.

Comment: `b = a[:,:-2] + a[:,1:-1] + a[:,2:]` will get both in one go :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bottleneck](https://pypi.org/project/Bottleneck/) library, as recommended by the notes in Numpy [sliding_window_view()](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) documentation:

```
>>> a = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
...               [ 2,  6,  8,  3,  5,  6,  8,  9,  1,  2]])
>>> bottleneck.move_sum(a, 3)
array([[nan, nan,  6.,  9., 12., 15., 18., 21., 24., 27.],
       [nan, nan, 16., 17., 16., 14., 19., 23., 18., 12.]])
```

or, if you want the exact output type and size:

```
>>> bottleneck.move_sum(a, 3)[:,2:].astype(int)
array([[ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [16, 17, 16, 14, 19, 23, 18, 12]])
```

Cons: Returns an array of floats of the same size filled with NaNs.

Pros: Neat. Very fast:

```
>>> %timeit sliding_window_view(a, 3, axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)
19.4 µs ± 489 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit a[:,:-2] + a[:,1:-1] + a[:,2:]
2.31 µs ± 138 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit bottleneck.move_sum(a, 3)[:,2:].astype(int)
776 ns ± 2.32 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit bottleneck.move_sum(a, 3)
254 ns ± 40.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```